# How to use Stylus in a Heroku Sinatra app

Tags: heroku, sinatra, stylus

I've just started experimenting with Sinatra, deployed to Heroku, and so far I've been able to  come to grips with the basics really quickly. Having said that, I'm a bit stuck on how to enable and use Stylus within my application.

Based on what I've read of the Sinatra documentation, this is how I've structured my very basic app.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'stylus'
require 'stylus/tilt'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

In addition, here are the contents of my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0'
gem 'thin'
gem 'haml', '>= 2.2.0'
gem 'stylus'
```

After using Bundler, and pushing my repo to Heroku it seems as though the necessary goodness is happening – console output shows that stylus, stylus-source and execjs (which I'm assuming is responsible for compiling the .styl files) are being included correctly.

My questions then are:

a) Where would the .styl files live? My current folder structure is:

```
app -
  Gemfile
  Gemfile.lock
  Procfile
  app.rb
  public -
    stylesheets
  views -
    layout.haml
    index.haml
```

b) How do I compile/reference the .styl files? Linked in the head, referenced in the route, or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) I put any stylesheets (uncompiled) into `app/views/stylesheets/`.

b) You can either precompile them into `app/public/css` and then reference them the way you would reference any other external CSS, with a `link` in the `head` (which is how I do things) or, you can use the way you've set up for, by compiling via a route call, e.g.

```
get "/screen.css" do
  stylus :"stylesheets/screen"
end
```

You will probably want to add in some kind of [caching](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Cache%20Control) with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Iain. I get an 'Internal Server Error' with the route setup you're proposing, but precompiling before pushing the repo seems like an obvious and easy enough solution.

Comment: @ChrisH Nae bother :) You shouldn't need the `require`s in the Sinatra app for Stylus then, and take a look at https://rubygems.org/gems/guard-stylus for automating it (there are other watcher libraries too, take your pick).